# write a python code the most efficient way

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am writing a code using a Python library MDAnalysis.
And I have an array (502,3) of atom positions 
I want to get an array of bonds (vectors of position of Atom(i+1) - Atom(i))
And then I want to obtain an average tensor qab =  which is essentially a np.outer(ua,ub)
averaged by all atoms.

I can rewrite this code using fortran subroutines but I think it would be more pleasing to see a delicious numpy slicing solution:) Here is my code that I wrote and that works, I want to make it faster and prettier. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
bb = u.selectAtoms("all")
coor = bb.positions
print coor.shape # return is (502,3)
# the coordinates of the atoms that we split on 3 dimensions
bbx = coor[:,0]
bby = coor[:,1]
bbz = coor[:,2]
#the bond vectors we obtain by subtructing atoms positions 
bbx_ave = bbx[:-1] - bbx[1:]
bby_ave = bby[:-1] - bby[1:]
bbz_ave = bbz[:-1] - bbz[1:]
#now we concentrate everything back so we have one big array
bb_res = np.vstack((bbx_ave, bby_ave, bbz_ave))
# print bb_res.shape # the return is (3,501)
# now we have an array of bonds

# qab - the result tensor which we want to get
nq = len(bb_res)
qab = np.zeros((3,3))
count = 0.

for i in xrange(0, nq):
    for j in xrange(0, i+1):
        qab = qab + np.outer(bb_res[:,i], bb_res[:,j])
        count += 1.
qab = qab/count
print qab
[[ 0.21333394  0.5333341   0.        ]
 [ 0.5333341   4.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think your double for loop isn't doing what you want it to. If you had `xrange(0, nq)` on both loops it would produce a different result (but it would take about twice as long). It seems that you are trying to take advantage of symmetry and save time by only summing over half the tensor. But when doing this you should include the fact that the off diagonal terms are twice as important as the diagonal terms. To see this more clearly, try working out a simple example where `nq=2` by hand.

Comment: Now you have `nq == 3` whereas it would make much more sense if it's `nq === 501`

Answer (score 1):

I've done my best below. It's pretty easy to generate your `bb_res` more efficiently, but I was unable to optimize the double `for` loop. On my computer, my method is about 26% faster. Also based on the statement of your question I believe there is a bug in your code which I pointed out in a comment. I have fixed this bug in my answer, so it produces a slightly different output than your code.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

# create some mock data
coor = rand(502,3)

def qab(coor):
  # this is the transpose of your bb_res
  # transposing is as simple as bb_res.T
  bb_res = coor[:-1] - coor[1:]

  nq = bb_res.shape[1]
  out = np.zeros((3,3))

  for i in xrange(0, nq):
    for j in xrange(0, i):
      tmp = np.outer(bb_res[i], bb_res[j])
      out += tmp + tmp.T
    out += np.outer(bb_res[i], bb_res[i])
  return out / nq**2

print qab(coor)
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't add `2*` the outer product, but instead the outer product and its transpose, to get the same output as when both loops would run to `nq`. And `nq` should be equal to `bb_res.shape[0]`?

Comment: @moarningsun, I am taking advantage of symmetry in the problem. This symmetry is `np.outer(bb_res[i], bb_res[j])` = `np.outer(bb_res[j], bb_res[i])`.

Comment: Please verify, the symmetry should be: `np.outer(bb_res[i], bb_res[j]) == np.transpose(np.outer(bb_res[j], bb_res[i]))`

Comment: Oh derp, how did I forget this? Thanks, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now you can replace the nested loop with `out = np.einsum('ij,kl->jl', bb_res, bb_res)`, which doesn't exploit symmetry but gives a nice speedup nonetheless `:)`

Comment: Does the "->jl" part tell it to explicitly sum over i and j even though they are not repeated indices? I've looked at the `np.einsum` documentation but I have trouble understanding how the of from `np.einsum` notation with the '->' to mathematical tensor notation.

Comment: I agree the notation of einsum is not so easy to understand. In my mind `ij,kl` says take the full "outer" product and then `->jl` says to "collapse" to the second and fourth dimension (by summing the first and third dimension). An alternative way of doing the same would be `np.multiply.outer(bb_res, bb_res).sum(axis=(0,2))`

Comment: Exactly; the rhs of einsum contains all indices retained after the product; all omitted indices are summed over. This gives more explicit control over summation behavior than the standard Einstein summation convention of repeated indices.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `nq = bb_res.shape[1]` in your code snippet, I can reproduce the output with the following vectorized code:

```
d = np.diff(coor, axis=0)
I, J = np.triu_indices(d.shape[0])
print np.dot(d[J].T, d[I]) / len(J)
```